# sql syntax error - not able to append string to a database

Tags: c#, sql, database, syntax-error

I am currently working on a dummy project in which I am making a login screen. I don't have any big intentions with the project, beside learning some C# and sql.

I am currently trying append a new user to the database which contains each username and their password, but I am for some reason getting an error message.

The entry written in the textbox should be stored in the database, but for some reason is this not happening..

I am getting an error stating I have a syntax error which I am not sure i understand.

```
private void create_user_username_box_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Add user/password to database when when someone leaves the area. 
     using (DbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
     {
         connection.Open();
         using (DbCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[information] (id,password) VALUES ("+create_user_username_textbox.Text+","+create_user_password_textbox.Text+");"))
         {
             command.Connection = connection;
             command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.'
         }                


    }                
}
```

Comment: Your syntax error will be because you aren't adding single quotes around the string values in your SQL.As an aside, look into using SQL parameters to construct your SQL statements - using concatenation like that leaves you wide open to SQL injection attacks and is generally considered a *very* bad thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not do the following, ever

```
"INSERT INTO [dbo].[information] (id,password) 
     VALUES (" + someStringVariable + "," + someOtherStringVariable + ")"
```

Just think about what you're doing here - you're putting whatever text the user entered directly into your query string. This is the easiest way to have your database dropped or all the information it contains stolen.

Instead, use prepared statements

```
     var commandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[information] (id,password) VALUES (@Username, @Password)"

     using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
     {
         command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = create_user_username_textbox.Text
         command.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = create_user_password_textbox.Text
         command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
     }
```

You should also strongly consider NOT storing passwords in plain text

Updated with suggestion to replace `Parameters.AddWithValue` - obviously if the column type on your database is different, set it accordingly

Comment: `AddWithValue` doesn't seem to pop up by autocomplete?

Comment: I think that's because you've specified the `command` variable as a `DbCommand`, use `var` or `SqlCommand` instead

Comment: @Due [you shouldn't use AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) anyway.

Comment: Updated @Crowcoder, not 100% sure of best practices regarding lengths of varchars though (it would be a pain to go through and update if you ever extended the max username length, for example)

Comment: You don't need to set the length, it will automatically use the length of the input data. I pretty much use the overload that is just name and sqldbtype, then I set the `Value` property, like you have done in your edit.

Answer (score 0):

The values are strings so the resulting SQL command text should enclose them within single quotes.

```
VALUES ('"+create_user_username_textbox.Text+"','"...
```

However, you should really parameterise the query to prevent the potential for Sql injection attacks.

Change the string to:

```
VALUES (@id,@pw)"))
```

Add parameters to the command:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", create_user_username_textbox.Text));
command.Paramaters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pw", create_user_password_textbox.Text));
```

Comment: `;` also needs to be removed from the query string!

Comment: I seem to get error message: `No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments` @SteveHarris

Comment: note also that using parameters instead of string concatenation has other advantages: beside protecting you from SQLInjection, it also saves you from the need of escaping "special" characters user can insert (what if a user insert `Shaquille O'Neal` as user name?)

Comment: Updated - needs to be new SqlParameter

Answer (score -4):

try this -

```
private void create_user_username_box_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // Add user/password to database when when someone leaves the area. 
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
 {
     connection.Open();
     using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[information] (id,password) VALUES ("+create_user_username_textbox.Text+","+create_user_password_textbox.Text+");"))
     {
         command.Connection = connection;
         command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.'
     }                


}                
}
```

Comment: Answer is same as OP's question!